# Problems chaining val(), text() and data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$select.append($("<option />")
    .val(this.id)
    .text(this.text)
    .data('name', this.name)
    .data('isstorage', this.isstorage));
```

It correctly sets the `<option>` tag's `value` and text values. But it doesn't set the `data-name` or `data-isstorage` attributes.

Can someone tell me what I have wrong here?

Full example:

```js
var $select = $('#myselect');

var x = {
  id: 'id',
  text: 'text',
  name: 'name',
  isstorage: 'isstorage'
};

$select.append($("<option />")
    .val(x.id)
    .text(x.text)
    .data('name', x.name)
    .data('isstorage', x.isstorage));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="myselect" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make this into a [mcve]?

Comment: .data isn't for setting attributes, it's for setting the dataset properties.  If you want to actually see the attributes, use `.attr('data-name', this.name);`

Comment: @RobertMcKee: I find this confusing. `$el.data('name')` returns the value of the `data-name` attribute. You're saying `$el.data('name', 'abc')` doesn't set it?

Comment: Yes, it does not set an attribute.  What actually happens is the data-* attributes are consumed and loaded into the element's dataset property.  Jquery will read/set the values there, but it's a one-way ticket, the set values don't go back to data-* attributes.  The content IS there though.. add `console.log($('#myselect option:first').data('name'))` to the bottom of your code pen, and you will see in the console it outputs name.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.attr('data-name', this.name)
.attr('data-isstorage', this.isstorage));
```

.data() is for parsing not setting content